How to correctly inflate and convert this layout to bitmap, with correct dimensions
I'm having issues converting layout to Bitmap keeping the correct dimensions.
This is what I have in my layout file:

And this is what I get as the result:

It creates the wrong dimensions, and seems that gravity for the text is ignored.
(I'm creating a Bitmap to add as google maps Marker)
Here is my XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/street_label"
  android:layout_width="40dip"
  android:layout_height="30dip"
  android:background="@mipmap/ic_marker_middle">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="G" />
</FrameLayout>

And my Java code:
private Bitmap createStreetLabel(String labelText) {
    View cluster = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.street_label,
      null);
    TextView clusterSizeText = (TextView) cluster.findViewById(R.id.label_text);
    clusterSizeText.setText(labelText);
    cluster.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
      MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    cluster.layout(0, 0, cluster.getMeasuredWidth(),cluster.getMeasuredHeight());
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cluster.getMeasuredWidth(),
      cluster.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    cluster.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
  }

